# Avahi fails in buildroot running intltool-update

Tags: buildroot, avahi

I'm using an older buildroot 2016.11 and want to add DNS-SD by selecting the avahi package. Resulting in this error:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*)\${ <-- HERE ?([A-Z_]+)}?(.*)$/ at /home/user/nuvoton/nuc980/output/host/usr/bin/intltool-update line 1065.
checking for intltool >= 0.35.0...  found
configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.35.0 or later.
```

When searching I learned intltool should be enabed on the host, but I could not find how in menuconfig.
More searching told me it is related to some Perl update
I tried adding this patch http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2017-June/194509.html but that also didn't help.

Can somebody steer me in the right direction how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/maximeh/buildroot/blob/master/package/intltool/0001-perl-5.26-compatibility.patch makes avahi build without problems.

In my case the build is getting too big, so I have to trim it down somehow...